# JAX-RS : Model and Best practices

Tags: java, spring, jersey, jax-rs

I have a JAX-RS service (I use Jersey), and now I have to do the client. I was wondering how you guys use to deal with the model objects.
Do you put you model classes in a different jar in order to share it between the client and the server? Do you always use DTO or do you sometimes (always?) returns jpa entities.

The service I have to use (I haven't created it but I can modify it), often returns entities so I was wondering if it wasn't a bit weird if I externalize those classes.

What do you think? What are you use to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the complexity of the project and on the purpose you use JAX-RS in it:

- for very simple projects I wouldn't create one more DTO layer whatsoever
- for a project like yours that seems to use JAX-RS just to move data from a java client to a java server I wouldn't create one more layer either. That's because you are in charge at both ends (client and server) and because you reuse the same objects in both places (putting them in a separate jar and maven module is a good idea)
- for projects that use JAX-RS to expose an API to external clients it's a good idea to separate the model from the API with DTOs so they are allowed to evolve independently. For example you don't always want to expose all the fields via an API or to break your clients when changing something in the model.

**LATER EDIT**

- for a project that transfers only a subset of their model data fields to the client a DTO layer is useful for efficiency reasons

Comment: IMHO a DTO layer is often needed for several reasons: 1) Separation of concerns 2) Output size optimization. In my case, some services returns a relatively large amount of data, and I need DTO objects to send only the relevant fields. That's my first experience with jax-rs, but I guess a good practice (I mean, to make things very clean, even if it takes time to do that) is to externalize a DTO layer and the service interface. No?

Comment: It depends, as I've said. I thought you might need (almost) all the fields in your client for the user interface. But JPA entities are just POJOs, is not a such a mix of concerns to have them on the client. And I think the benefit of maintaining just one layer instead of  2 outweighs the "ugliness" of JPA annotations on client.